# Как написать свойство для ipnput

Tags: html, css

Есть ниже принтскрин inputov.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как написать 2 css свойства, что бы тень внутри inputa была как на картинке, и чтобы при выделении выделялось синим цветом тоже с тенью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я понял внутренняя тень только сверху:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 20px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Внешняя тень:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,94,255,1);
```

Если хотите подредактировать не зная как вот вам генератор: 
http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Хотите знать как, вот вам мануал: 
http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-shadow